# How to pick part of text file in directory and print section with STRIPOS in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, stripos

I am trying to read text from files in a directory and have it be displayed as description text below an image.  I have been able to use the STRIPOS function to separate out each part of the text, except am having trouble with the last section.  The last section is titled "Description:" and actually runs into multiple lines.  I don't know how to display more than just the line that reads "Description:".  I want to print from "Description:" to the end of the file.  I will post my code and the text file in this message.

```
$dirname = 'data';

$dirhandle = opendir($dirname);

$housestextarray = array();

if ($dirhandle)
        {
            while (false !==($file = readdir($dirhandle)))
            {
                if ($file !='.' && $file !='..')
                {
                    array_push($housestextarray, $file);
                }
            }

            closedir($dirhandle); 
        }

    sort($housestextarray);


    foreach ($housestextarray AS $housedescription)
        {
            $housetext = '';

            $description = '';

            $pos = stripos($housedescription, 'house_');

            if ($pos === false)
            {
                //nothing
            } else {
                    $lines_in_file = count(file($housedescription));

                    $fp=fopen($housedescription,"r");

                    for ($cntr = 1; $cntr <= $lines_in_file; $cntr++)
                {
                    $cityline=fgets($fp);
                    $priceline=fgets($fp);
                    $bedroomsline=fgets($fp);
                    $bathsline=fgets($fp);
                    $footageline=fgets($fp);
                    $realtorline=fgets($fp);
                    $grabberline=fgets($fp);

                    $descriptionline=fgets($fp);

                    //print $cityline;
                    //print $descriptionline;

                    //$housetext .= $line;

                    $citypos = stripos($cityline, 'City:');

                    if ($citypos === false)  //found the city line first time
                    {
                        //nothing
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $city= $cityline."<br />\n";
                        //print $city;
                    } 

                    $pricepos = stripos($priceline, 'Price:');

                    if ($pricepos === false)  //found the city line first time
                    {
                        //nothing
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $price = $priceline."<br />\n";
                        //print $price;
                    } 

                    $bedroomspos = stripos($bedroomsline, 'Bedrooms:');

                    if ($bedroomspos === false)  //found the city line first time
                    {
                        //nothing
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $bedrooms = $bedroomsline."<br />\n";
                        //print $bedrooms;
                    } 

                    $bathspos = stripos($bathsline, 'Baths:');

                    if ($bathspos === false)  //found the city line first time
                    {
                        //nothing
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $baths = $bathsline."<br />\n";
                        //print $baths;
                    } 

                    $footagepos = stripos($footageline, 'Footage:');

                    if ($footagepos === false)  //found the city line first time
                    {
                        //nothing
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $footage = $footageline."<br />\n";
                        //print $footage;
                    } 

                    $realtorpos = stripos($realtorline, 'Realtor:');

                    if ($realtorpos === false)  //found the realtor line first time
                    {
                        //nothing
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $realtor = $realtorline."<br />\n";
                        //print $realtor;
                    } 

                    $grabberpos = stripos($grabberline, 'Grabber:');

                    if ($grabberpos === false)  //found the grabber line first time
                    {
                        //nothing
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $grabber_formatted = str_replace('Grabber:','', $grabberline);
                        $grabber = "<h3>".$grabber_formatted."</h3><br />\n";
                        //print $grabber;
                    } 

                    $descriptionpos = stripos($descriptionline, 'Description: ');
                                                                    if ($descriptionpos === false)  //found the description line first time
                    {
                        //nothing
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $description .= $descriptionline."<br />";

                        //print $description;

                    }
                }
                    $output = $grabber."<br/>".$city.$bedrooms.$baths;
                    $output .= $price.$footage.$realtor."<br />";
                    $output .= "<br />".$description."<br />";

                    print $output;

            }
```

And here is the text file contents example (one of six files):

City: OceanCove 
Price: $950,000
Bedrooms: 5
Baths: 3
Footage: 3000 sq. ft.
Realtor: Shirley Urkiddeng
Grabber: Fantastic Home with a Fantastic View!
Description: 
You will never get tired of watching the sunset
from your living room sofa or the sunrise
from your back porch with a view overlooking
the gorgeous coral canyon.  Once in a lifetime
opportunity!

UPDATED CODE WITH Branden's help:

```
    function houseDescriptions()
{
    //$DOCUMENT_ROOT = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    //$dirname = $DOCUMENT_ROOT.'data';
$dirname = 'data';

$dirhandle = opendir($dirname);

$housestextarray = array();

if ($dirhandle)
        {
            while (false !==($file = readdir($dirhandle)))
            {
                if ($file !='.' && $file !='..')
                {
                    array_push($housestextarray, $file);
                }
            }

            closedir($dirhandle); 
        }

    sort($housestextarray);


    foreach ($housestextarray AS $housedescription)
        {
                        $housetext = '';

                        $description = '';

                        $data ="";

                        $pos = stripos($housedescription, 'house_');

                        if ($pos === false)
                        {
                            //nothing
                        } else {
                            $file_handle = fopen($housedescription, "r");
                    $data = "";
                    while (!feof($file_handle)) {
                       $filestrings .= fgets($file_handle);
                    }
                    fclose($file_handle);

                    //You'll need to double check the Regex if it doesn't work.
                    $data = preg_split('#\b(City:|Bedrooms:|Baths:|Footage:|Realtor:|Grabber:|Description:)\b#', $filestrings);

                    $city = $data[0];
                    $bedrooms = $data[1];
                    $baths = $data[2];
                    $footage = $data[3];
                    $realtor = $data[4];
                    $grabber = $data[5];
                    $description = $data[6];                    
                    $output = $grabber."<br />".$city.$bedrooms.$baths;
                    $output .= $price.$footage.$realtor."<br />";
                    $output .= "<br />".$description."<br />";

                    print $output;

            }   

        }
        //return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Updated with proper regex

fgets can have issues when trying to get a string out of text file, especially a long string, there may be a line break within it that you may not see in your text editing program. A better way to do this is to get all of the information from the text file and store it in a string, then handle all searches with [preg_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php). This code below (assuming my regex is correct, you may need to recheck it) will get all of the variables from the text file for you.

```
//Append the file location to the file name
$housedescription = $dirname."/".$housedescription;

//Get all contents of the file and save them into $filestrings
$file_handle = fopen($housedescription, "r");
$data = "";
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
   $filestrings .= fgets($file_handle);
}
fclose($file_handle);

//Remove any pesky \n newlines that were added by the text file
$filestring = preg_replace("/[\n\r]/","",$filestrings); 

//Case Sensitive Regex Search, split the string into an array based on the keywords
$data = preg_split('/(City:|Price:|Bedrooms:|Baths:|Footage:|Realtor:|Grabber:|Description:)/', $filestring, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

//Save all the keywords to vars
$city = "City: ".$data[0];
$bedrooms = "Bedrooms: ".$data[1];
$baths = "Baths: ".$data[2];
$footage = "Footage: ".$data[3];
$realtor = "Realtor: ".$data[4];
$grabber = "Grabber: ".$data[5];
$description = "Description: ".$data[6];
```

Notice the addition of $filestring = preg_replace("/[\n\r]/","",$filestrings); this will remove any extra new lines that were in the text file so there are no 
's where you don't want them.

Of course the absolute ideal would be to store all of your data in a mysql database instead of .txt files, as it is more secure and much faster for data access. But if you prefer .txt try not to open the same file more than once.

Some notes to take from this: [How to use Regular Expressions](http://weblogtoolscollection.com/regex/regex.php/), [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), [fgets](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php), [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

Comment: Thanks Branden! I'm new to all of this though and I transferred the code in but am getting an endless loop error of: Warning: feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/homelist2.php on line 104

Warning: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/MAMP/htdoc

Comment: I updated the question above to show the code that I put in to match what you provided me.

Comment: It also doesn't seem to be separating by the tags.  If I do a print $city I get everything in text as well as the text being repeated multiple times, where the same file is re-output later in duplicate in between the output of the next files...no clear pattern.

Comment: If I am r3ading your code correctly, $housedescription should equal a string of the name of a text file right? So $housedescription would equal say house_1.txt correct?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on the regex I provided in the code "#\b(City:|Bedrooms:|Baths:|Footage:|Realtor:|Grabber:|Description:)\b#" which would explain why you would get back the entire files contents. the preg_split() command takes the code and splits it at the deliminators provided by the regex, so if the regex is incorrect it wouldn't split it anywhere.

Comment: Thanks, I am too new to where what I've read about regex I don't really understand yet.  That's correct about $housedescription it leads to house_file.txt.  Thanks so much.

Comment: I have updated the preg_split line to properly split the data, the end of the preg split was also missing the -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY command which skips spaces between the deliminators and the following text. The above code should work. If you are still getting the feof loop error please do a echo $housedescription; at the top of your foreach loop and let me see what that comes up with. It should list your file.txt's and the path to them (ex: houses/house1.txt) or whatever your proprietary naming system is.

Comment: I'm still getting the same fgets and feof expects parameter 1 to be rsource, boolean given error.  The printout for the $housedescription is right.  It prints: house_bayview_1.txthouse_bayview_2.txthouse_mallard_1.txthouse_moduler_1.txthouse_townhome_1.txthouse_white_house.txt Also, I am wondering if there is a way that I could keep the titles for the sections, ie. Price:  ?  THANKS!

Comment: Sure, that would be as simple as adding $city = "City: ".$data[0]; to each of them. If you were to do it with the preg_split it could cause some issues. Try adding fopen($dirname."/".$housedescription, "r"); it looks like your $housedescription variable does not contain the directory prefix where the files are located. When you call fopen it needs to know exactly where the text files are in relation to where your program is. So either use $dirname."/".$housedescription, or in the begining of the foreach loop add $housedescription = $dirname."/".$housedescription. I will update my answer.

Comment: let me know if this fixes your problem, if so please select the check for my answer :) Good luck Brad

Comment: Thanks Branden! I'm all straightened out now.  You rock!!